# “ENOENT: no such file or directory, open” when attempting to save an image through multer's storage. Symbols are not the issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

For some reason if I attempt to save an image through multer's storage, I get this error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\Chat Backend\public\images\servers\1596819056816AFKay.jpg'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\Chat Backend\\public\\images\\servers\\1596819056816AFKay.jpg',
  storageErrors: []
}
```

My multer setup looks like this:

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images/servers')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
    }
})

var fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
}

app.use(multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image'));
```

If I were to not use storage and just stick to dest, it saves the image just fine.

```
app.use(multer({ dest: 'public/images/servers' }).single('image'));
```

I've checked a lot of similar questions but their problem is usually that the name of the image contains symbols which are not allowed, whereas that is not the case with me because I've tried the simplest names (just a string for example) and I still get the error. Why might this error be happening?

Comment: It could be how your defining the path. Have you tried: `'./public/images/servers'`?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I am on windows OS. This helped:

```
new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + file.originalname
```